# Query Expression With Join on Multiple Columns Causes ArgumentException During Test Run But Not At Runtime

Tags: c#, linq, exception, xunit

This snippet of code causes the `ArgumentException`, shown below. What's weird is that it only occurs during unit test execution. When the app runs, this code runs, and works. I guess that could mean it's a data issue? I can look further into that.

I've tried setting the anonymous types, in the join, to have the same column names, by doing something like `A = ...` and `B = ...` in both anonymous types, but that doesn't change things.

Below is my query:

```
var query =
  (from account in db.AccountDetails
    join team in db.Teams on new { account.CompanyId, account.TeamCode }
      equals new { teams.CompanyId, teams.TeamCode } into groupedTeams
    from team in groupedTeams.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where account.CompanyId == message.CompanyId && account.ProcessId == message.ProcessId
    select new
    {
      AccountDetail = account,
      Team = groupedTeams.FirstOrDefault()
    }
  );
```

Exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: Expression of type '' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Packing.ColdCamperEtl.Business.Data.Elmer.Models.Tax]' of method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`2[Packing.ColdCamperEtl.Business.Data.Elmer.Models.AccountDetail,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Packing.ColdCamperEtl.Business.Data.Elmer.Models.Tax]]] GroupJoin[AccountDetail,Tax,<>f__AnonymousType1`2,<>f__AnonymousType0`2](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Packing.ColdCamperEtl.Business.Data.Elmer.Models.AccountDetail], System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Packing.ColdCamperEtl.Business.Data.Elmer.Models.Tax], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Packing.ColdCamperEtl.Business.Data.Elmer.Models.AccountDetail,<>f__AnonymousType1`2[System.String,System.String]]], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Packing.ColdCamperEtl.Business.Data.Elmer.Models.Tax,<>f__AnonymousType1`2[System.String,System.String]]], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`3[Packing.ColdCamperEtl.Business.Data.Elmer.Models.AccountDetail,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Packing.ColdCamperEtl.Business.Data.Elmer.Models.Tax],<>f__AnonymousType0`2[Packing.ColdCamperEtl.Business.Data.Elmer.Models.AccountDetail,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Packing.ColdCamperEtl.Business.Data.Elmer.Models.Tax]]]])'
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateOneArgument(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, Expression arg, ParameterInfo pi)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateArgumentTypes(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, ReadOnlyCollection`1& arguments)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression instance, MethodInfo method, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.GroupJoin[TOuter,TInner,TKey,TResult](IQueryable`1 outer, IEnumerable`1 inner, Expression`1 outerKeySelector, Expression`1 innerKeySelector, Expression`1 resultSelector)
```

Why would this be happening?

Comment: Is the GroupJoin usage correct, this is Inner Join

Comment: To have the Left Outer Join you shall use `db.Teams.DefaultIfEmpty()` in the Join statement itself, not post joining

Comment: error complains about Packing.ColdCamperEtl.Business.Data.Elmer.Models.Tax model, I would  check if that property is properly initialized in Unit Tests?

Comment: @DeepakKumar That was it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @BobHorn glad I could help, MrinalKamboj I think Bob joined correct way, This is syntactically correct as shown in example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins